# Facebook Tab Image

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

O.K. I added a facebook app to the side of my facebook links. But it's showing up as a plain and dull star. Can I change this image to something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the bookmark icon (which is also used if your app is installed on a page tab) it's in your app settings, under 'Basic Info' -> 'App Images' -> Icon and should be a 16x16 image.

Comment: Basic info is my actual information. CTRL+F nor I see App Images, I see App - which leads me to all my applications I have on my page, but when I go to edit the static HTML second tab one I can only change the name

Comment: If the App you've installed on the page isn't one you Admin yourself you won't be able to change the icon - it sounds like you're using a third party App like https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196 in which case you're stuck with whatever the App developer selected